# Is there a way to sort EntityQuery using property name strings?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is there a way to sort `EntityQuery` using property name strings?

Seriously, I have an `EntityQuery` and the name of a property.  I need to call `OrderBy` with only the name of a property.  How can I do this? Reflection gives me the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Method
>   'GetValue' on type
>   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' is
>   not accessible. Only methods on
>   primitive types, System.Math and
>   System.Convert are supported in
>   queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build an expression tree like this.

```
Type entityType = typeof(T);
var px = Expression.Parameter(entityType,"x");
var ex = Expression.Property(px, propertyName);

var lx = Expression.Lambda<Expression<Func<T>>(ex,px);

var q //.. Entity Query

q = q.OrderBy(lx);
```

You should replace T with your type, this is not generics example.